# Why onclick is not working?

Tags: javascript

```
var  btn = document.querySelectorAll('.button');

 function  test() {
    alert('hello')
}


btn.addEventListener("click", test);
```

After clicking on the "button" - `test` function should be called, bit it's not.

Comment: there is because querySelectorAll return a list of elements, you should cycle the array and add your handler to all elements

Comment: There is [Stack Overflow in Russian](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/) if you prefer to ask questions in Russian.

Answer (score 0):

'.button' will search for all elements with class named 'button'. If you are searching for button elements you should write: document.querySelectorAll('button')

Additionally querySelectorAll gives nodeList. 
For this code:

```
<button id="myBtn">Try it</button>
<button id="myBtn2">Try it</button>
<script>
    var  btn = document.querySelectorAll('button');
    console.log(btn);
</script>
```

return will be  NodeList[button#myBtn, button#myBtn2], as you can see it is an array.

Answer (score 0):

> document.querySelectorAll would return the list of elements. You need
>   to apply the click event on individual elements.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

```js
var  btn = document.querySelectorAll('.button');
console.log(btn[0]);
 function  test() {
    alert('hello')
}


btn[0].addEventListener("click", test);
```

```html
<div class = 'button'>Button</div>
```